# How can I detect if javascript files are being blocked by IE11 security settings?

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer

I have a site that renders nearly everything through javascript (not my design), and this has caused a lot of issues in Internet Explorer, of course. The recurring issue is that when the user has security set to High, the necessary javascript files get blocked, I believe because they are from another domain. This has something to do with the Drupal setup, I'm not entirely sure, but the important thing to know is that the files are served from a different domain and there's nothing I can do about that.

What my client wants is for an alert to pop up whenever these scripts are getting blocked that tells their users how to change their security settings.

1) If I add a javascript file on the same domain, it shouldn't get blocked, right?

2) Is there a way I can detect what the user's security settings are, or detect if scripts are being blocked using javascript?

Comment: If the user has security set to high, then **all** scripts will be blocked independent of the scripts domain.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to detecting whether a js script was loaded or not; there could be so many things, it can be their network firewall, os level firewall, browser security settings, the list continues with possibilities.

You can have:

```
<script src="http://yourdomain.com/the_js_script.js"></script>
<script>if (typeof foo == "undefined") {alert ('error loading script');}</script>
```

Make sure in the_js_script.js, you'd have

```
var foo = 'Script loaded successfully';
```

You can do that for all the js scripts, and alert distinct messages so the user at least knows which scripts were blocked or if they came through.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your IE security set to High, disables all scripts from running in the browser.

The only workaround available is to place a warning message using the `noscript` html tag.

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would have liked to comment on @unixmiah's answer, but I don't have enough reputation, and I believe this is an answer as well. Unixmiah's solution won't work to alert blocked clients, I think since the alert needs a script to be generated.However, I believe this would work (wouldn't it?):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("p#jstrap").hide();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="jstrap">You seem to have switched Javascript off.</p>
```